# Java Factorial Calculation for program can not do 0,1,2 How can I fix this

Tags: java, factorial

```
// Factorial Calculation
                double factorial = 1;
                factorial = firstNumber;
                for(double i = factorial-1; i > 1; i--){
                       factorial = factorial * i;
                       // Makes result equal to the firstNumber
                       result = factorial;
                     // To continue the program
                     continue;

                 }
                // Displays the result for factorial
                System.out.println("factorial of " + firstNumber + " is " + form.format(result));
                // To continue the program
                    continue;
```

So I have to a calculator by using switch statements everything works except for when I do the factorial calculation, if I enter 0,1 or 2 the answer is always 0, but from  3 to 10 the answer is always correct. So firstNumber is the variable that the user inputs. Factorial is the number it will calculate I had to make it like this so when I display my message the firstNumber equals the number not the result.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: If you enter a 0, 1, or 2 for which variable?

Comment: You don't need `continue;` and when you do need `continue;` you shouldn't comment it like that!

Comment: @Gendarme It does if i enter 3 it displays 6 , 4 is 24 ,5 is 120 so fourth i tried doing just factorial it gives me 5 is 600.

Comment: @GBlodgett judging the print statement, the factorial of `firstNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `result` is presumably initialized to `0` (e.g. `int result = 0;`).

What is happening is that when you enter a number smaller than `3`, that means `factorial-1` is smaller than `2`, and since we're dealing with integers, that means not larger than `1`. The condition of your loop is that `i` must be *larger* than `1`, so you never enter your loop, and `result` never changes from its initial value. A quick fix could be to simply change `i > 1` to `i > 0`; there is no harm in multiplying by `1` anyway.

You should also initialize `result` to `1`, since you won't enter your loop for the values `0` and `1`, but that's fine since their factorials are both `1`.

Comment: And what is the purpose of using the variable `result`? It can be eliminated entirely, and just use the final value of `factorial`.

Comment: Yes, the code in its entirety should be changed. I only gave a quick fix, enough to answer the question.